# How to do inventory adjustments for more than 50k products?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to do inventory adjustment for more then 50k > products. But odoo not able to do. Every time show error time exceeds. It take too much time, any way to do speedy.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it might be best to develop a [queue](https://github.com/OCA/queue/tree/10.0) process to process pieces of this in a batch. The [linked modules](https://github.com/OCA/queue/tree/10.0) are from OCA and are a base for others to develop their specific queues.

In your case, it may require manual or automated splitting of the Inventory Adjustments into smaller batches or (ideally) you can process `x` lines at a time, such as:

```
 stock_inventory.line_ids.filtered(lambda r: r.state == 'draft')
```

*Note: It doesn't look like the above code will actually work because all `stock.inventory.line` "Status" are just related to the `stock.inventory`. You'll probably need to override this to be manually updated or take a different approach.*

[Documentation on `filtered`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#other-recordset-operations)